# How to read typescript error stack traces correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

How to read typescript error stack traces correctly?

I understand that `tsc` generates `.js` files from `.ts` ones.

Also, the stack trace of any error should eventually tell me a function failed on `filexyz.js:123:45`.

Now, if I go to the `filexyz.ts` file source code, ie, before "compilation" and look for row 123, will I be looking at the right row?

Comment: No, `filexyz.ts` and `filexyz.js` will have different content and the line numbers won't match, if you want to be able to translate between the two, you'd need to ensure your compilation is configured to emit "source maps".

Comment: That feature is called "sourcemap". Search about "typescript sourcemap" and you'll get everything that you need. nodejs loads sourcemaps by default, and the same for chromium based browsers. When you read about it and know the different options, I recommend using *inline* sourcemaps.

Comment: Thanks. If I'm just running a service in a container, for example..after enabling source map I assume the error printed to stde will still not match right?

Comment: If the software that is running inside the container is loading the sourcemaps, yes, you will see the source code.